# How to get the type of an object in php?

Tags: php, python, object, types, instance

In Python I normally do `print type(someObject)` to view the type of a variable value. I now need to do a similar thing in php in which I want to print the type to the syslog. So I do this:

```
syslog(LOG_ERR, gettype($myObject));
```

The result is

```
Apr 30 13:54:09 php0 php: object
```

I presume the object is an instance of a my class called `ReceivedMail`, but since it just prints out `object` I have no way of knowing this.

Is there a way to print the type of an object (or the class it was instantiated from) to the syslog in php? All tips are welcome!

Comment: var_dump(object) will print the class name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is for debugging or logging, you can use [`get_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php).

If you need to verify an object's class you will typically use `instanceof` because of polymorphism.